# How to grep this pattern: "LEJ|???|WRO"?

Tags: shell, unix

I'm trying to find the files with lines: `LEJ|xxx|WRO`

The 3 characters in between to be ignored..

tried

```
grep -l LEJ|???|WRO *
```

it doesn't work.. any advice?

Answer (score 2):

First off .. you haven't mentioned what error you're seeing ("doesn't work" is not an error), but I suspect that the command you've posted in your question probably breaks because the vertical bars are being interpreted as pipes, rather than as part of the regular expression.  As a general rule, whenever you need to use punctuation as a command line option, wrap it in quotes, preferably single quotes.

The subject of your post says `LEJ|*|WRO`, and your text mentions `LEJ|xxx|WRO`. From this I infer that you want the text "LEJ" followed by a vertical bar, followed by EITHER any number of other characters OR three characters, followed by another vertical bar, followed by "WRO".  You weren't clear with this in your question, but you clarified this in comments below -- you want three characters between the vertical bars.

The string you're handing to grep is not a regex that describes the pattern above.  First off, note the following regex rules:

- `.` (a dot) matches any single character (as an "atom").
- `?` (question mark) is a modifier that says "zero or one of the previous 'atom'".
- `*` (asterisk) is a modifier that says "zero or more of the previous atom".
- `|` (vertical bar) denotes a logical "or", joining multiple expressions together.  Thus `(one|two)` will match "one" or "two".
- `[..]` (square brackets) denotes a "range", containing a set of characters to be considered an atom.

To create an expression that is understood as "one or more characters", you could use, for example `..*`. This literally means "any single character, followed by zero or more of any single character".  To mean "any three characters", you'd use `...`.

These characters are magic. If you include them in your expression, they have magic properties.  If you want to actually MATCH one of them, you need to ESCAPE them.

Now .. there are a few different "types" of regular expression.  In Basic RE (BRE), the or bar by itself is not magic.  In all other types (including Extended RE (ERE)), it is.  One of the magic characteristics of a range is that it removes the magic of other characters, so to escape the vertical bar, we can put it in a range.

So ... a regex to match your string might be:

```
LEJ[|]...[|]WRO
```

This notation is compatible with both Basic (BRE) and Extended (ERE) formats, so it doesn't matter whether you use it with `grep` on the command line or PCRE functions in some other language.

This answer is not intended to be an exhaustive tutorial in how to use regular expressions. As with any language, there is more than one way to express things.  While this should solve your stated problem, its real goal is to give you some hints that will help you figure out your next regex a little more easily.

Here are some fun resources for you:

- https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=re_format
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/
- https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: Thanks for your inputs.. I meant any 3 characters in between the pipes

Comment: You should [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33747769/edit) to clarify this point, as I suggested in my answer.  `LEJ|*|WRO` says nothing about 3 characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `egrep 'LEJ\|.{3}\|WRO'`

`|` is a special character in regex syntax. To search for it you need to escape it in your pattern by preceding it with a backslash, as in `\|`.

Comment: `|` is a special character in regex syntax. To search for it you need to escape it in your pattern by preceding it with a backslash, as in `\|`.

Comment: You did. I was just explaining why you did it.

Comment: golf: you can save a character with `grep 'LEJ\|...\|WRO'`

Comment: Oh, that's right, with BRE, `\|` is special. Even shorter then: `grep 'LEJ|...|WRO'`

Comment: Correct! That's neat.

Comment: when you are using single quotes does it intrepret the 3 dots for 3 characters?

Comment: @Ash2win, a dot is a single character in a regex, and your quotes don't affect the dot. Quotes will affect things that your shell *expands*.  Search for `EXPANSION` in your shell's man page (you may find a few different types).